# Trigger to sync quote with opportunity

Tags: apex

Trigger to sync quote with opportunity whenever Quote is created for an opportunity and

Quote custom field - Is_Primary__c = true.

Below is the code works when quote is created. but how to include condition "Is_Primary__c = true" in below class?

```
Trigger:
trigger QuoteAutoSync on Quote (after insert)
{
    Map<Id, Id> quoteMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Quote currentQuote : Trigger.New)
    {
        quoteMap.put(currentQuote.Id, currentQuote.OpportunityId);
    }
    QuoteAutoSyncUtil.syncQuote(quoteMap);
}

Handler class:
public class QuoteAutoSyncUtil
{
    @future
    public static void syncQuote(Map<Id, Id> quoteMap)
    {
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
        for(Id currentQuote : quoteMap.keyset())
        {
            System.debug('currentQuote -->'+currentQuote);
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Id = quoteMap.get(currentQuote);
            opp.SyncedQuoteId = currentQuote;
            oppMap.put(opp.Id, opp);
        }
        update oppMap.values();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that condition in Quote Level,you can include your condition like this.

```
for(Quote currentQuote : Trigger.New)
{
  if(currentQuote.Is_Primary__c==true){
   quoteMap.put(currentQuote.Id, currentQuote.OpportunityId);
 } 
}
```

Comment: its okay..its annappa !!!

Comment: +1, but `if(currentQuote.Is_Primary__c)` is sufficient; you don't need to compare it to true. This avoids the trap where you accidentally type `=` instead of `==` and it mysteriously breaks.